# Can't chain two api calls to a mongo database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to change from a Mongo document:
1. One property from all objects inside an array
2. One property from one object inside an array.

I looked at mongoose docs and it says that exec() makes your query a complete `promise`. Well I don't quite understand that then I tried chaining them but I'm not sure if I'm doing it ok.

route.js

```
router.patch("/internado/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const updateOps = {};
  for (let prop in req.body) {
    updateOps[prop] = req.body[prop];
  }

  User.update(
    { _id: id },
    // this changes every element from object inside array
    // already tested the command in postman
    { $set: { "datosAcademicos.internados.$[].activo": false } }
  )
  .exec()
  .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      res.status(200).json(result);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: err });
    });

  User.update(
    { _id: id },
    // pushs the new element to array. Also tested by itself on postman
    { $push: { "datosAcademicos.internados": updateOps } }
  )
    .exec()
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      res.status(200).json(result);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: err });
    });
});
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all , both updates will end at some time ,

and the faster one will return and answer (res.send) and close the connection.
when the second update finishes res.send is closed already and will raise exception.

You are not guaranteed which one will finish first , and if order does matter to you , you should really chain then and not just write them one after the other .

if it does not matter to you , or you care about only one of the results , 
reflect it in your code .

So if you want to chain then (one after the other):

```
// lets execute the first update
User.update(
  { _id: id },
  { $set: { "datosAcademicos.internados.$[].activo": false } }
).exec()
// now we wait for it to finish
.then(res => {
   // do something with the first update ?
   // possibly res.send if you did like

   // now execute the other Update
   return User.update(
      { _id: id },
      { $push: { "datosAcademicos.internados": updateOps } }
   ).exec()
})
.then(res2 => {
   // possible res.send / other logging
   res.send('done all updates');
})
.catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
   res.status(500).json({ error: err });
});
```

If you want to execute them together without waiting for the first one:

```
Promise.all([
   User.update(
     { _id: id },
     { $set: { "datosAcademicos.internados.$[].activo": false } }
   ).exec(),
   User.update(
      { _id: id },
      { $push: { "datosAcademicos.internados": updateOps } }
   ).exec()
])
// wait for both of them to finish , order not guaranteed 
.then(result => {
   // result[0] - result for first update
   // result[1] - result for second update ..
   res.send(result);
})
.catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
   res.status(500).json({ error: err });
});
```

If you only care about just one result but still want to execute both of the updates , just reflect it in your code so you don't call res.send twice .

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. I still got `(node:19284) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` error. But I comment out the first `res.json` and problem solved. Do you know if there is any drawback on doing what I did??

Comment: It’s not a matter of a drawback . It’s the problem you call res.send/res.status potentially twice ... once from the then and once again from the catch .